# What is meant by "non-negative polynomial"?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Recently I was reading through some practice problems for my linear algebra class and a question said we are allowed to assume the following.

If $f$ is a non-negative polynomial function on $[−1,1]$ and if $f(a)>0$ for some $a∈[−1,1]$, then $\int_{-1}^{1} f(t)dt >0$.

In the above statement, what is meant by non-negative polynomial? For reference we are working in the vector space of all polynomials of at most degree $n$.

Comment: It probably means $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$

Comment: I would assume that a non-negative polynomial is a polynomial that only takes non-negative values.  If, say, we are working over $\mathbb R$, then $x^2$ is non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

The key is that it says $f$ is a non-negative *function* on $[-1, 1]$. So it just means $f(t) \geq 0$ for $t \in [-1, 1]$.